# search bar and search display text view not centered

Tags: storyboard, searchbar

This problem seems to be related to layout constraints? But storyboard seems not to allow this kinds of constraints set.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out that it's due to index tableview, if I remove it than this problem will not surface.